# Only trivial solution to a pair of constrained linear diophantine equations

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, diophantine-equations, additive-combinatorics, integer-programming

Given positive integer $n$, we are looking for a set
of $n$ positive integers $a_i$.

The following linear integer program must have only
the trivial integer solution of all ones.

- $0 \le x_i \le \frac{n}{2}$
- $\sum x_i = n$
- $\sum a_i x_i = \sum a_i$

One exponential example is to take $a_i=C^i$.

We experimented with an integer programming solver and
couldn't find small solutions, possibly because of
the law of small numbers.
To our surprise taking $n=30$ and random numbers in the range
$[2^{29},2^{30}]$ gave non-trivial solutions.

> Q1 How small can $\max a_i$ be in terms of $n$?
> Can we get $\exp(o(n))$?

> Q2 If $\max a_i$ is polynomial in $n$, what bound
> can we get for the number of solutions of the integer program?

Comment: Up to $n=7$ it's possible to check exhaustively and find $(1, 2)$, $(1,2,3)$, $(1,2,3,5)$, $(1,2,3,5,8)$, $(1,5,6,17,25,27)$, $(2,10,12,34,50,54,55)$. For $n=8$ I have $\max a_i \ge 75$ and will continue searching, but am not optimistic of finding a definitive answer.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks. How do you search? Bruteforce or ILP solver? I think I can strengthen n/2 to n/4 or even smaller bound, will edit the question.

Comment: Exhaustive search, but it's not quite brute force for $n \ge 6$. There's a useful optimisation from noting that the solution set $A$ must satisfy $|A + A| = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ (and probably higher order constraints, so maybe worth tagging [tag:additive-combinatorics]). [Python code](https://gist.github.com/pjt33/491942c46a7392382fa1685116ca15ce).

Comment: Actually, I think there must be a bug in my code. The minimal solution should have $a_1 = 1$.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks. I think for $n$ so small it is very difficult to distinguish polynomial from exponential. I am trying opportunistic approach:  generate candidate $a_i$ and run integer program solver, but deciding more than one solution is not very feasible.

Comment: Found and fixed the bug. For $n=7$, the optimal $\max a_i$ is 54, and one solution can be obtained by subtracting one from each value in the example I gave earlier. For $n=8$ the optimal $\max a_i$ is 107, and one solution is $(1, 3, 11, 43, 86, 87, 91, 107)$.

Comment: If we require $x_i \le 2$, this is equivalent to requiring that any two subsets of $\{a_i\}$ of the same cardinality have different sums. Strengthen that requirement to "any two subsets of $\{a_i\}$ have different sums" and Elkies, *An improved lower bound on the greatest element of a sum-distinct set of fixed order* gives $\max a_i > 2^{-n} \binom{2n}n$. That's suggestive that the answer to Q1 will be negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the first question is negative.

Let $A$ denote the set of weights $\{a_i\}$. Strengthen the first constraint to $0 \le x_i \le 2$.

If we have two different subsets $S_1, S_2 \subset A$ of the same cardinality, their sums must be different, since otherwise we can assign $$x_i = \begin{cases} 2 & \textrm{if } a_i \in S_1 \setminus S_2 \\
0 & \textrm{if } a_i \in S_2 \setminus S_1 \\
1 & \textrm{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ to get a second solution to the program.

Therefore the $\binom{n}{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$ subsets of half of the weights (rounded down) must all have different (positive integer) sums, so that one of those subsets must have weight at least the number of subsets, and the sum of all of the weights must be at least $\binom{n}{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} + \binom{\lceil n/2 \rceil + 1}{2} = \Theta(n^{-1/2} 2^n)$.

Thus $\max a_i \in \Omega(n^{-3/2} 2^n)$.

Comment: Thanks, I have some doubts about your proof, since you don't use $\sum x_i=n$. If we have $a_1+a_2+a_3=a_4 + a_5$ setting $x_1=x_2=x_3=2,x_4=x_5=0$ we have $\sum x_i=6 \ne 5$. I think the following is explicit counterexample to your claim, what is solution with {0,1,2} to: a_i=[1, 5, 25, 11, 20]

Comment: @joro, I think you're overlooking "*of the same cardinality*" in the description of $S_1, S_2$. (And on reflection I should say explicitly that $S_1 \neq S_2$). Feel free to edit if you have a clearer way to rephrase that.

Comment: Indeed, you are right, missed that, sorry.