# Only trivial solutions to system of linear diophantine equations possibly related to hamiltonian cycles in graphs

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, additive-combinatorics, integer-programming

This might be related to [counting hamiltonian cycles](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429025/counting-hamiltonian-cycles-in-graph-and-finding-a-coefficient-of-polynomial).

@**Peter Taylor** gave [negative result](https://mathoverflow.net/a/428266/12481) about the one dimensional case, but we believe his attack is
not directly applicable to this question.

Given positive integer $n$, find integer $m$ and $m \times n$
matrix $A = a_{i,j}$ with positive integer entries.

Let $y_1,...,y_n$ be integer variables.

Consider the following integer program with constraints:

- $0 \le y_i \le n$
- $\sum_{j=1}^n y_j = n$
- For $ 1 \le i \le m$: $\sum_{j=1}^n y_j a_{i,j}= \sum_{j=1}^n a_{i,j}$

We require the integer program to have unique solution
of $y_i$ all ones for chosen $(m,A)$. Let the solution be $(m_0,A_0)$.

> Q1: How small the unique solution can be in terms of $n$? Can we get
> $2^{m_0} \max ( a \in A_0)=\exp(o(n))$?

Getting $O(\exp(n))$ is easy by taking $m=1,a_{1,i}=2^i$.

Comment: I agree that the argument for the one-dimensional case doesn't carry over directly for $m \ge 2$. Have you tried fixing $m=2$ and selecting random weights up to $2^{\sqrt{n}}$, or even just up to $n^2$?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Certainly I tried to pick low hanging fruit :) So far can't tell if I failed or not. I am using the "ISL" ILP solver, but currently can't find reference. Probably will release the sagemath +ISL code.

Comment: @PeterTaylor ISL is at [https://www.openhub.net/p/isl](https://www.openhub.net/p/isl)

Comment: @PeterTaylor One experimental observation: If you start with $m=1$ and have many solutions, going to $m=2,a_{2,i}=a_{1,n+1-i}$ basically a_2 is reversed a_1, then the solution might be unique.

Comment: The negative result extends to any constant $m$, that is, an affirmative answer (if it exists) should have $m$ growing with $n$.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Thanks, this is useful. Would you please answer why m can't be fixed?

Comment: Assume for a moment that $n$ is a perfect square and $n=m^2$.
This assumption is not essential I think, just easier.
The idea is to partition $m^2$ numbers $(y_j)$ in $m$ blocks of $m$ digits in base $n+1$.

Define $a_{ij} = (n+1)^{j-m(i-1)-1}$ if $m(i-1) \lt j \le mi$ and $0$ otherwise.

Then $2^m \cdot \max a_{ij} = 2^m (n+1)^{m-1} \le 2^m (n+1)^m = \exp (\sqrt{n} \log (2n+2))$.
The question asked for positive $a_{ij}$ rather than just non-negative,
but because of $\sum_{j=1}^n y_j = n$ we can add $1$ to all $a_{ij}$.

Comment: @JeroenNoels Many thanks for the clever idea, please answer. I think in your notation you swap row and columns compared the question notation. Also when taking logarithms, my sagemath implementation doesn't agree with your bound, might be my bug.

Comment: @joro  I will check and write an answer with a bit more detail. I want to use the same notation as in the question, but I think there might be a small typo in there: I assume you meant $\sum_{j=1}^n y_j a_{i,j}= \sum_{j=1}^n a_{i,j}$ so with $y_j$ instead of $y_i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we can get $\exp(\omicron(n))$.

Assume for a moment that $n$ is a perfect square and $m=\sqrt{n}$.
The general case is essentially the same, just a bit more complicated.
The idea is to partition those $n=m^2$ variables $y_1,\ldots\, y_n$ in $m$ blocks of $m$ digits in base $b=n+1$. Define

$$a_{ij} = \left\{  
  \begin{array}{ll} 
     b^{\,j-m(i-1)-1} & \text{if } \; m(i-1) \lt j \leq mi \\ 
     0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{array} 
  \right.
$$

For example if $n=9$ we have $m=3$ and $b=10$ and

$$ A = \left( 
       \begin{array}{rrr|rrr|rrr}
         1 & 10 & 100 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
         0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 10 & 100 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
         0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 10 & 100 \\
       \end{array}  
       \right) $$

It is not hard to see that such $A$ only admits the trivial solution where all the $y_j$ are equal to $1$, because $0 \le y_j \lt n + 1 = b$.

Now $\max a_{ij} = b^{m-1} \le b^m$  and thus

$$
2^m \cdot \max a_{ij} \le 2^m b^m = (2b)^m 
= \exp(m \, \ln(2b))
= \exp(\sqrt{n} \,\ln(2n+2)) 
$$

and $\sqrt{n} \,\ln(2n+2)$ is in $\omicron(n)$.

The question actually asked for *positive* integer entries $a_{ij}$ rather than just non-negative entries.
But because $\sum_{j=1}^n y_j = n$, we can instead use $a'_{ij} = a_{ij} + 1$, and since
$\,\max a'_{ij} = b^{m-1} + 1 \le b^m$
we arrive at the same bound.

**Edit** (based @joro's comment)
In summary, we have $\sqrt{n}$ equations with $\max a_{ij} \sim n^{\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: Many thanks, I like this. You have $\max a_{ij} \sim n^{\sqrt{n}}$, right?

Comment: @joro Yes, that's right! And it is helpful and illuminating to express that directly in terms of $n$. I will make a small edit.

Comment: Congratulations, you won the bounty. Hope you win more bounties.

Answer (score 3):

Below I show that $m$ cannot be constant.

The given system of $m$ equations can be reduced to the case of $m=1$, that is, to a single equation:
$$\sum_{j=1}^n y_j a'_{j} = \sum_{j=1}^n a'_{j}$$
where $a'_{j} := \sum_{i=1}^m a_{ij}b^{i-1}$ with $b:=n\cdot \max a_{ij}+1$. The key observation is that both sides of each equation
$$\sum_{j=1}^n y_j a_{ij} = \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}$$
is less than $b$ (under the constraint $\sum_j y_j=n$).

Then, by the negative result of Peter Taylor, we have
$$\frac{(n\cdot\max a_{ij} + 1)^m}{n} > \max a_{ij}\cdot \frac{b^m-1}{b-1} \geq \max a'_{j} \in \Omega( n^{-3/2} 2^n ),$$
implying that $\max a_{ij} \in \Omega( n^{-1-1/(2m)} 2^{n/m} )$, which would contradict the given asymptotic bound if $m$ is constant.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like there is positive answer here. Besides the potential connection with counting cycles, is this problem a theoretical challenge?

Comment: @joro: if you want a practical challenge in cycle counting - try to compute further terms of https://oeis.org/A109468